# Python OpenAI Atari module in Ubuntu 16.04 - "No module named atari_py."

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, openai-gym

(I'm new to Ubuntu, excuse any ignorance.)  I'm trying to run SpaceInvaders in Python using OpenAI's Atari module, however I keep getting the error

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py",
>   line 11, in  raise error.DependencyNotInstalled("{}. (HINT:
>   you can install Atari dependencies by running 'pip install
>   gym[atari]'.)".format(e))gym.error.DependencyNotInstalled: No module
>   named atari_py. (HINT: you can install Atari dependencies by running
>   'pip install gym[atari]'.)

The command suggested in the error is exactly what I used to install gym.  I've read in [another forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103338/python-no-module-named-how-to-use-pip) that this means not all the dependencies are loaded, so I've taken great care to download this dependencies listed [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/README.rst).  Here's some proof that they're properly installed:

```
$ dpkg -s python-numpy python-dev cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev xvfb libav-tools xorg-dev python-opengl libboost-all-dev libsdl2-dev swig | grep  Status
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
```

Is there anything else I should be aware of, or another way I can be troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have meet same problem. I have solve this problem with fellowing step.

```
➜  OpenAIGym cd gym
➜  gym git:(master) pip install -e '.[all]'
```

or

```
pip install -e '.[all]'
```

because `pip install -e .`  only is minimal install.

```
OS: maxOS
env: Python3.6
```

Thanks